How do I create a new shape key from mix under the currently active shape key instead of at the end of the list using a script?
I want to make sure that when creating a new Shape Key (New Shape From Mix), it is not created at the end of the Shape Keys list, but right under the very shape key from which I get it (active), as when duplicating; I am not strong in scripting, and using a search engine, I was able to get the following script:
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
i = -1
obj = bpy.context.active_object
shape_name = obj.active_shape_key.name

## enable shapekey before copying
skey_value = obj.active_shape_key.value
obj.active_shape_key.value = obj.active_shape_key.slider_max

obj.shape_key_add(name=str(shape_name), from_mix=True)

## reset shapekey
obj.active_shape_key.value = skey_value

shape_key = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[i]
keys = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.keys()
shape_key_index = keys.index(shape_key.name)
obj.active_shape_key_index = shape_key_index

    

This code creates a New Shape From Mix and selects it at the end of the Shape Keys list... and then I got stuck(
I thought:

Change the index of New Shape From Mix, but I don't know how to do it with a script;
Use bpy.ops.object.shape_key_move (type = 'UP'), but I don't know how to set it in the script to stop when it is under the desired shape key;
Try sorting Shape Keys by name and assigning the New Shape From Mix index equal to its position in the Shape Keys list, but did not find a way to do this in the search engine.
Try to duplicate the shape key and add data from New Shape From Mix there, but I don't know how.
Maybe mute all objects in Shape Keys except the active one, do New Shape From Mix, select it at the bottom of the list, and apply bpy.ops.object.shape_key_move (type = 'UP') until we reach another unmute object and unmute all? but how to do all this with a script...(((

Please help the noob with the script)

My first unresearched though is that if you know how many shape keys there are total, and you know which one is selected by number, you can just run the move(UP) operation the number of times that is the difference between the two. Do you have or can you find those two numbers?

Hello, is it possible to somehow ask that this be determined in the script itself?

to determine the index/number in the list of the current shape key, and then start the move operation (UP) number of times, which is the difference between them?

Answering your question: I do not know how to find these numbers using the script (
